# Reading Cache elements of a web Application

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I have a web application in my local system in which a bunch of services have been implemented.I cached few responses of theses services and put them in memory.Now I want to monitor all these cache elements (in externally project or a package in which these caching is implemented)  and should be able to read all the data in it(i.e, all the elements that has been cached till this point).How can it be done ??

Comment: What do you have so far? Show some code and where you're stuck.

Comment: What exactly means monitor? What is the purpose of it? Do you mean it in the sense of the memcache monitoring interface or do you mean it in the broad sense of presenting application statistics?